# App Crash during Automated unit testing using XCTest iOS

Tags: ios, swift, automation, xctest

I am getting crash on trying automated unit test using XCTest. Written "testLogin" function.

```
func testLogin() {

    let controller  = ViewController()
    controller.usernameTextField.text = "username"
    controller.passwordTextField.text = "password"
   controller.LoginPressed(self)

    XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

username and Password Text fields are IBOutlets of the controller. But when I try to test the app using XCTest, app is crashing at usernameTextField saying the value is nil. How can an IBOutlet be nil.. Did I miss any setup here?

Answer (score 2):

IBOutlets are nil until the viewDidLoad method is called. In order to invoke it from unit tests, you should call the view controller's view property before accessing the outlets.
This will invoke the didLoad:

```
func testLogin() {

   let controller  = ViewController()
   controller.view

   controller.usernameTextField.text = "username"
   controller.passwordTextField.text = "password"
   controller.LoginPressed(self)
   XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a storyboard/xib to load a controller, the outlets are set by the system using the method `initWithCoder`. 
When you create your view controller with `ViewController()`, you are not creating that controller from a storyboard/xib but instead from a generic `init` method

```
//Creating the view controller from the init method
ViewController()

//Creating the view controller from a nib
UIViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerNibName", bundle: nil)

//Creating the view controller from a storyboard
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
storyboard = instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerIdentifier")
```

Using one of the bottom two methods for creating your view controller will set the outlets correctly. Use 2nd if the outlets are set in a xib or the 3rd if  they are set in a storyboard.